# Aptana won't load

Tags: aptana

I have used Aptana Studio 3 for several months.  I try to start it and get the following message "Could not launch the prodcut because the specified workspace cannot be created.  The specified workspace directory is either invalid or read-only".  It has worked perfectly up until receiving the above message.

Comment: I am using Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You should have mentioned if you using Windows or Linux or Mac. Could you please check the read/write permission of the workspace directory once. You can try to use different directory as workspace directory.

Comment: How would I use a different directory?  I have changed the read write permissions to allow both.  I just can't figure out if I can't get Aptana to start, how would I change the directory?

Comment: Could you please try by referring this

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1251-wont-start-workspace-cannot-be-created